# Visualizing All Coin Flip Combinations

Tags: r

Suppose I have a coin with 2 sides (S = Success, F = Failure). I wrote this R code to see all possible combinations that can occur in 5 flips:

```
outcomes <- c("S", "F")
combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), 5))
colnames(combinations) <- paste("Flip", 1:5)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
> head(combinations)
   Flip 1 Flip 2 Flip 3 Flip 4 Flip 5
       S      S      S      S      S
       F      S      S      S      S
       S      F      S      S      S
       F      F      S      S      S
       S      S      F      S      S
```

Using R packages (e.g. data.tree, igraph), I am trying to make a visualization which shows the possible combinations that can occur at each level:

```
library(data.tree)

generate_tree <- function(node, depth) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        return(node)
    } else {
        for (outcome in c("S", "F")) {
            child <- node$AddChild(name = outcome)
            generate_tree(child, depth - 1)
        }
        return(node)
    }
}

root <- Node$new("Start")

root <- generate_tree(root, 5)

print(root, "level")
# Is it possible to rotate the tree so you can read it from left to right?
plot(root)
```

[image]

**My Question:** In the above graph, I want to color all branches where 3 successes occur before 2 failure (e.g. shade the nodes "green"):

I know how to do this in tabular form:

```
outcomes <- c("S", "F")
combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), 5))
colnames(combinations) <- paste("Flip", 1:5)

check_successes_before_failures <- function(row) {
  successes <- sum(row == "S")
  failures <- sum(row == "F")
  return(successes >= 3 && failures < 2)
}

combinations$Three_Successes_Before_Two_Failures <- apply(combinations, 1, check_successes_before_failures)
 
head(combinations)

  Flip 1 Flip 2 Flip 3 Flip 4 Flip 5 Three_Successes_Before_Two_Failures
      S      S      S      S      S                                TRUE
      F      S      S      S      S                                TRUE
      S      F      S      S      S                                TRUE
      F      F      S      S      S                               FALSE
      S      S      F      S      S                                TRUE
      F      S      F      S      S                               FALSE
```

**But is it possible to color the nodes on the graph like this?**

Thanks!

Comment: You say "I want to color all branches where 3 successes occur before 2 failure" but that doesn't seem to match up with the green colored node in the example. You have SSSSS which is all success and no failures. And you have FSSSF colored but not FFSSS. So what exactly is the rule for highlighting?

Comment: @mrflick: thank you for your reply and pointing this out. I will revise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the leaves, and then walk from each leaf to the root to see how many failures there are. This seems to do the trick

```
root <- Node$new("Start")
root <- generate_tree(root, 5)

for (leaf in root$leaves) {
  path <- leaf$Get('name', traversal="ancestor")
  if (sum(path=="F") < 2) {
    leaf$Do(function(x) SetNodeStyle(x, inherit = FALSE, style="filled", fillcolor = "#d0eabb"), traversal="ancestor")
  }
}
SetNodeStyle(root, style="filled", fontcolor="black")
plot(root)
```

[image]

This highlights all paths with less than 2 failures.